# Two Dimensional Array not printing values in matrix format

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to work on some 2 dimensional array examples. While I was trying to print the 2 dimensional array output in the following format

```
0 1 2 

3 4 5 

6 7 8 

9 10 11 

12 13 14
```

My output was showing up as like this

```
0 

1 

2 

3 

4 

5 

6 

7 

8 

9 

10 

11 

12 

13 

14
```

Not exactly sure what's seems to be the problem

Here is my code:

```
public class TwoDArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int rows = 5;
        int columns = 3;
        int k = 0;
        int[][] array = new int[rows][columns];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                array[i][j] = k;
                k++;
            }

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                System.out.println(array[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Use `print` instead of `println` in nested loop if you don't want to add line separator.

Comment: Also, the given program doesn't produce the output you say its producing.

Comment: Jonathan, i am not getting the output in matrix format , instead it is printing column wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used :

```
System.out.println(number)
```

This will create a new line at the end of each number printed. To see output as you want it, you should use :

```
System.out.print(number)
```

CODE:

```
public class TwoDArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int rows = 5;
        int columns = 3;
        int k = 0;
        int[][] array = new int[rows][columns];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                array[i][j] = k;
                k++;
            }
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When i executed your program i got the required result, but I don't see any differences in mine and yours code , could you please explain whats the difference.,what i committed wrong.Thanks.

Comment: See my second for loop. Specifically, when I am printing a number, I use **System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");** whereas you are using **System.out.println(array[i][j] + " ");**

Comment: Thankyou Vaibhav , using Print in nested loop instead of println working :)

Comment: Mind you, in java, println() specifies to the compiler that you want an ENTER at the end of the line. This is called a 'newline'. The print() statement is used when you do not want that 'newline'.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing new line every time you print an element.

Use this code. It should solve your problem:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```